# Как осуществляется отправка заявки на почту в jquery корзине SaleJS?

Tags: javascript, json, post

Добрый день. 
Нашел скрипт http://salejs.com/ru.html для создания простого "интернет магазина" на LP, весь  функционал устраивает, но вот только не пойму как отправляется заявка на почту, если подключить store.js с сайта разработчика, как написано в документации, заявка приходит, а если подключить его со своего сервера, то выскакивает ошибка. там есть небольшой мануал [видео-мануал 9мин](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=alYof3FLEZ0) но я не понимаю, откуда берется директория orders и вообще как сделать так чтобы заявка отправлялась с моего сервера а не сервера http://salejs.com

Почти разобрался с серверной частью, письма приходят, но пустые, не пойму как вывести в письме данные из объекта order, который передается серверу методом post:

```
    // Cross domain request.
  var server = {}
  server.send = function(method, url, data, callback){
    if(!window.FormData || !window.XMLHttpRequest)
      return callback(new Error("Your browser doesn't support that feature, please update it."))
    var formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('data', JSON.stringify(data))
    var responded = false
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open(method.toUpperCase(), url, true)
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(responded) return
      if(xhr.readyState == 4){
        responded = true
        if(xhr.status == 200) callback(null, JSON.parse(xhr.responseText))
        else callback(new Error(xhr.responseText))
      }
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
      if(responded) return
      responded = true
      callback(new Error("no response from " + url + "!"))
    }, timeout)
    debug(method, url, data)
    xhr.send(formData)
  }
  server.post = function(url, data, callback){this.send('post', url, data, callback)}
// Sending order.
    app.on('send order', bind(function(){
      if(app.contacts.isValid()){
        // Preparing order.
        var order = {
          price             : this.cart.totalPrice(),
          emailOrdersTo     : this.emailOrdersTo,
          site              : window.location.host,
          currency          : this.currency,
          language          : this.language
        }
        extend(order, this.contacts.toJSON())
        extend(order, this.cart.toJSON())

        // Clearing the cart and showing success message.
        this.cart.removeAll()
        var message = '<div class="cart"><div class="cart-message">'
        + escapeHtml(t('orderSent')) + '</div></div>'
        this.cartPopupView.show(message)

        // Sending order to server.
        server.post(this.baseUrl + '/form/storeformprocessor.php', order, bind(function(err){
          if(err){
            var message = '<div class="cart"><div class="cart-message cart-message-error">'
            + escapeHtml(t('orderFailed')) + '</div></div>'
            this.cartPopupView.show(message)
          }
        }, this))
      }
    }, this))
```

вот php

```
<?php
$emailSubject = "Новая заявка с " . $_POST['site'];

$emailBody = "\n\nДанные по заявке:\n\n"; $headers = 'From: Питахайя ' . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$emailBody .="Заполнена форма: " . $_POST["name"] ."\r\n";

$resultOfMail = mail("second@email.ru", $emailSubject, $emailBody, $headers);

if ($resultOfMail) { echo '{"success":true}'; } else { echo '{"success":false}';
} ?>
```

Comment: Документация там на удивление бедная, и про собственную серверную часть там ничего нет. Так что, видимо, будет подобие реверс-инжиниринга запросов и разработка под них APIшки. Что как-то многовато для одного ответа .-.